# Is there a way to get the columns from a joined table in the model instance dict object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
t = PurchaseHeader.objects.first()
t.__dict__
{
  '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f4b34aa7fa0>, 
  'id': 3, 
  'ref': 'jhkh', 
  'goods': Decimal('-100.00'), 
  'discount': Decimal('0.00'), 
  'vat': Decimal('-20.00'), 
  'total': Decimal('-120.00'), 
  'paid': Decimal('-120.00'), 
  'due': Decimal('0.00'), 
  'date': datetime.date(2020, 11, 7), 
  'due_date': datetime.date(2020, 11, 14), 
  'period': '202007', 
  'status': 'c', 
  'created': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 7, 15, 46, 48, 191772, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
  'cash_book_id': None, 
  'supplier_id': 1128, 
  'type': 'pc'
}
```

When I joined the supplier table I was disappointed to find that the columns are not included in the dict.  Below, `t.__dict__` is the same as above.  I noticed that the Supplier model instance is cached inside of `t._state` so I guess I could create my own method which all models inherit from which does what i want - all the columns from all tables inside a dict.  But I wondered if anybody knew a way of doing this sort of thing out of the box?

```
t = PurchaseHeader.objects.select_related("supplier").first()
t.__dict__
```

Answer (score 0):

`select_related`'s goal is actually to prefetch data so that it doesn't need to be fetched in a second query when accessing `"supplier"`. Instead it already fetched this data using a join in the original query.

If you want to obtain a `dict` based of your model that also contains the data of a relation in it, your best bet is using `ModelSerializer` with a nested serializer. Assuming that your supplier model is called `Supplier` it would look something like this:

```
class SupplierSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = ['name', 'other_field'] # Add more Supplier fields

class PurchaseHeaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supplier = SupplierSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseHeader
        fields = ['supplied', 'vat', 'total'] # Add more PurchaseHeader fields
```

You can then use the `PurchaseHeaderSerializer` like this:

```
purchase_header = PurchaseHeader.objects.select_related("supplier").first()
the_dict_you_want = PurchaseHeaderSerializer(instance=purchase_header).data
```

Comment: Thanks although this obviously depends on django rest framework which might not be installed for the project.  I asked because I'm surprised / disappointed that django doesn't provide a neat method for doing this already.

Comment: Fair remark, you would indeed need DRF to use this solution. I guess you could also just implement `__repr__` for your `PurchaseHeader` class and construct the `dict` you want using `__dict__` on both the header and the supplier and put the result of the supplier in the header `dict`. Can be done with 2-3 lines of code. However depening on how big your project will become I think DRF might be a nicer solution.